# R if value in column 1 in table a matches value in column 1 in table b, copy value from column 2 in table b into table 1

Tags: r

#Question# I have 2 dataframes. 1 dataframe (A) has multiple columns. Column 1 in dataframe A has an email address where multiple rows have the same email address. The other dataframe (B) has a list of unique email addresses in column 1 and in column 2 a count of how many times that email appears in the list in dataframe A. I want to essentially do a vlookup so that wherever the email address matches from both tables, it will pull the count into a new column into dataframe A. Can anyone assist?

## Data

```
Table A   
Column 1    Column 2      Column 3  
a@a.com     home          123   
a@a.com     house         456   
b@b.com     tree          221   

Table B   
Column 1    Column 2(Count)      
a@a.com        2   
b@b.com        1   

Expected result should be Table A with an additional column:   
Column 1    Column 2      Column 3     Column 4   
a@a.com      home           123             2   
a@a.com      house          456             2   
b@b.com      tree           221             1
```

Comment: @akrun added in question

Comment: If you already have two datasets, then you can also join (in general)  i.e. `library(data.table);setkey(setDT(df1), Column1)[df2]`  Suppose, if the 'Column2' value is some 'x', 'z' in Table2, this could be joined to create a new column

Comment: @akrun not sure why I am still getting error saying setDT function can't be found. I have loaded the data.table package

Comment: Can you show the version of data.table.  I am using the devel version, but I think even `1.9.4` would work with `setDT`

Comment: Where do i check the version?

Comment: Type `sessionInfo()` in the R console and you get the versions of all the packages that are loaded

Comment: My version is `1.9.5`.  So, it may be time for you to update to newer version

Comment: Updated package and now getting error cant find function setkey

Comment: Can you try it on a fresh R console (and after loading data.table)

Comment: Executed, but I get the following error: Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: result$email

Comment: I couldn't get the error with the devel version using the example you showed.

Comment: @akrun: do you know why R crashes after installing the new version of `data.table`?

Comment: If you are using an old version of R, you may also update that to newer version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need df2 to get the count. You can use df1 alone to get the  count:

```
#solution using data.table package
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,count:=.N,by=Column1]
   Column1 Column2 Column3 count
1: a@a.com    home     123      2
2: a@a.com   house     456      2
3: b@b.com    tree     221      1

#solution using dplyr package
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
group_by(Column1)%>%
mutate(count=n())
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: Column1

  Column1 Column2 Column3 count
1 a@a.com    home     123     2
2 a@a.com   house     456     2
3 b@b.com    tree     221     1
#Data
df1<-structure(list(Column1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a@a.com", 
"b@b.com"), class = "factor"), Column2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("home", 
"house", "tree"), class = "factor"), Column3 = c(123L, 456L, 
221L)), .Names = c("Column1", "Column2", "Column3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused. my df1 is called result and my column name is email.address. What is .N? I'm getting error saying setDT function can't be found

Comment: `.N` gives the you the number of number of rows in each group (which is Column1 here).

Comment: @TD Both of the solutions in this answer require the installation and loading of packages (seen in the `library` lines). That's the only way you can use `.N`, etc. for the first one.

Comment: I have loaded the data.table package and then I continue to recieve the same error saying setDT function can't be found

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Try updating the package.

Comment: Updated package and still no luck. The command started to execute but then returned errors and crashed R.

Comment: It did happen for me (not sure why). But once it crashed, you can restart R and then it will work.

Comment: Yup it works now. That is weird. Thanks for all the continuous help!!

Comment: No problem. Yes, it is weird.